# Flutter issue regarding navigate to a new screen

Tags: flutter

[image]

Hello I'm new in Flutter. when I try to import a new page to navigate new screen it shows error

Comment: This is just a warning, telling you that you are not using anywhere the file you are importing.

Comment: Just add/include this package Name in your Class, For example

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error, but a warning. You are importing the module 'signup.dart' (that takes a small computational cost) but you are not using it.

Flutter is just trying to make your app faster by warning you about the packages you are importing but not using. You can simply remove that line (line number 5)

Answer (score 0):

Navigate using these code:

Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignupPage()));

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.